# VS2010 debug c++ x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, ide, 64-bit

I wanted to debug my application as a 64 bit application in the VS2010 IDE. 
I set breakpoints, but they are ignored.

Is debugging for a 64bit application not allowed in the IDE?

I am using Win7, 64 bit. My application is a Windows console application. 
Nothing special is used.

Thank you.

Comment: I debug c++ x64 applications in Visual Studio 2010 every day in Visual Studio 2010 pro. When breakpoints are ignored usually the problem is the code you are breaking at was not compiled into your executable.

Comment: Where did you set your breakpoints, in a constructor by any chance?

Comment: For example within int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

Answer (score 1):

No, debugging 64-bit applications works just fine.